# Setting connector (edge) points in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm trying to import a diagram in our custom format to mxgraph, but am stuck on setting the points on the connector. I've tried called the functions in mxEdgeStyle like [ElbowConnector](http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxEdgeStyle-js.html):

```
ElbowConnector(view.getState(edge), model.getSource(edge), model.getTarget(edge), points)
```

where points is the array of point I want to set. I get the feeling I'm calling entirely the wrong function, or am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edge styles are style like the other key/value styles. In the link you provide to the API specifications, the top example tells you how to use it:

```
var style = stylesheet.getDefaultEdgeStyle();
style[mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE] = mxEdgeStyle.ElbowConnector;
```